How can I get autofill suggestions back in Google forms?
I was getting recently written data as a suggestion to autofill when I was submitting some Google forms. Now it's not happening. How can I get suggestions back so I can fill the forms fast as some things are have to be same every time.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The suggestions likely come from the browser (e.g., Firefox, Brave Browser, Tor Browser, etc.). Each browser is different.

For Firefox, Control whether Firefox automatically fills in forms should help.
For Chrome browser, see this SuperUser answer.
For Edge, see Appuals.

If you use another browser, look up "<browser name> form autocompletion" online.
And if you've recently created a new browser profile, reinstalled the browser, or performed cleanup on the profile, old suggestions may have been removed, but they should repopulate as you use the browser.
